# Trying to implement a function to create a linear space in Haskell but i'm getting a cast error

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to construct a function to create a linear space, similar to python.
Just to start the function I create this code:

```
lin x0 x1 tam zero
    | tam - zero > 0.0 = (x0 + (x1-x0)/tam) : x1
    | otherwise = x1
```

but i'm getting this error message:

```
<interactive>:2:45: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘x1’
      In the expression: (x0 + (x1 - x0) / tam) : x1
      In an equation for ‘lin’:
          lin x0 x1 tam zero
            | tam - zero > 0 = (x0 + (x1 - x0) / tam) : x1
            | otherwise = x1
    • Relevant bindings include
        zero :: a (bound at <interactive>:1:15)
        tam :: a (bound at <interactive>:1:11)
        x1 :: a (bound at <interactive>:1:8)
        x0 :: a (bound at <interactive>:1:5)
        lin :: a -> a -> a -> a -> [a] (bound at <interactive>:1:1)
```

**what am I doing wrong? And how could I fix it?**

Comment: Try adding a type signature for `lin` – that should result in a more helpful type error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the intention is that `x0` and `x1` are numbers, right? But `:` constructs a list out of a first element and another list containing the rest of the elements. So in

```
{- ... -} : x1
```

you are treating the number `x1` as if it were a list. Similarly, since one branch of the conditional returns a list, the other branch must, too, and your

```
| otherwise = x1
```

is interpreted as trying to return `x1` as if it were a list.

On the other hand, if the intention from the start was that `x1` should be a list, then the computation

```
x0 + (x1 - x0)/tam
```

(or, more specifically, `x1 - x0`) doesn't really make sense, because it appears to treat `x1` as a number instead of a list.

Comment: now i tried use ++ but still not working, how should i create this list?

Comment: @JoãoPauloAndrade I have no idea, because I don't understand what list it is you want to create. If you want more targeted help, you're going to have to say a bit more about what you want to happen -- for example, by giving some example input/output pairs or some more English description of how this function fits into your bigger plan. That said, generally, SO is not a code writing service. It's up to you to write the code; we'll help you over specific humps, but the better-defined the hump is the more likely you will be to get good help.

Comment: Thank you, you've solve my problem. I just needed to add an other list to it and append. I trying to create this function without need composition of functions but i think that's not possible with my actual knowledge. I wanna create the function linspace 
 of https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.14.0.0/docs/Numeric-Container.html by myself

Answer (score 2):

Since you use x1 on the right of a `:`, x1 must be a list of some sort. However you are also using x1 on the left of the `:` as if it were a number.  It can't be both and that is why you get the error message

In more detail, the compiler has figured out that `x0`, `x1`, `tam`, and `zero` all have the same type, which it calls `a` and that that is the type of `(x0 + (x1 - x0) / tam)`. Since the operand on the left of the `:` has type `a`, `x` must have type `[a]`. But `x1` also has type `a` and so the compiler tries to unify `a` with `[a]`, which it can't do.